# Eclipse IDE full path names in Editor tabs (project/filename.ext)

Tags: eclipse, tabs, editor, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Eclipse IDE (CDT especially), and there are two annoying things to me:

1. Editor tabs of files with equal names (in the same project or differen ones) looks the same. E.g. when i open main.c from two project simultaneously, i get who [main.c] Editor tabs with no idea which tab belongs to wich project.
2. Working with loosely-coupled projects simultaneously (e.g. main application and several shared libraries it uses) it's sometimes not easy to remember which source file belongs to which project, especially when you discover dozen of source files at a moment. And you have to hover over tabs again and again to see project they belong to.

So, the question is: is it possible to add prefixes to tab names so they loook in some way like: [project1/main.c] [project2/main.c] and so on?
I've been searching throughout Eclipse 3.5 and 4.2, but without any success. Also, almost all Eclipse screenshots on the Web looks the standard way (just filename.ext Tabs).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.